# How to fetch data depending on the route in @ngrx?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

We build a webapp where the user has to click through lists to get to a certain edit view. E.g. from the landing page, the user selects a *client*, then an *agent* and then gets to the edit view of that agent. The URL in that case would hold the IDs: `/client/4/agent/7/edit`. [@ngrx/router-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store) is used to handle URL-changes, so when the URL above is accessed directly, the edit view appears and works fine.

The app also contains a breadcrumb, which shows **not the ID but the names** of the pieces of path: *Client: Company > Agent: Postal > Edit* when `client = { id: 4, name: 'Company' }` and `agent = { id: 7, name: 'Postal' }`. We usually fetch this data(`client` and `agent`) when the correspondent list entry is clicked.

However, when a URL like `/client/4/agent/7/edit` is accessed directly, there is no `client`-Object stored that contains the name. **How can I fetch the object that belongs to a route when a URL is accessed directly in a reduxy way?** I know how I could *hack* this into the app, but the dataflow should remain nice and clean *reduxy*.

Things I've considered:

- Checking the existence of `client`, `agent` etc. in every component and fetching them, if they do not exist. This could be a lot of overhead and also, additionally the logic should go into selectors which cannot trigger an action.
- Using a service for checking if the data is already there - if not, load it. Would be checked on every URL change and could also slow down the application.
- Trigger the fetching of data on the initial load of the application - where to do that? `AppComponent`?

I'm also open to restructuring the whole application (use another routing, introduce @ngrx/effects, redefine the API etc.)

Comment: Have you tried to use "ngrx/router-store" ?!?
it will listen to every change on the URL and add into your redux store.

Comment: I write in the first paragraph that we use router-store. The problem is: where should I listen to router events - in the Breadcrum Reducer? And how can I know if the data (`client` and `agent`) is already in the state?

Comment: Sorry @frot.io, I've missed that you are already using @ngrx/router-store. This a really good example of something similar to what you are trying to do
https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-ngrx-refactoring/wiki/4.-Handling-router-state-with-@ngrx-router-store

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to create a custom [data service](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DefaultDataService, HttpUrlGenerator, Logger } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Hero } from '../../model/job/hero';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroDataService  extends DefaultDataService<Hero> {

  constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator, logger: Logger) {
    super('Hero', http, httpUrlGenerator);
    logger.log('Created custom Hero EntityDataService');
  }

  public setEntitiesUrl(entitiesUrl) {
    this.entitiesUrl = entitiesUrl;
  }

  public setEntityUrl(entityUrl) {
    this.entityUrl = entityUrl;
  }

}
```

Then register it in your entity store module:

```
  constructor(
    heroDataService: HeroDataService
    ) {
    entityDataService.registerService('Hero', heroDataService);
  }
```

Then in your component, set your custom path before making you call your EntityCollectionService (ie, for entityCollection)

```
this.heroDataService.setEntitiesUrl('myCustomPath');
this.heroes$ = this.heroService.getAll();
```

For single entities call setEntityUrl method instead.